# Try to fix a <form> in an <img>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap and i try to fix a form in a img but when i resize the form move like i dont want

Here my website in 1860 x 900

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K66bF.png

and here in 1400 x 768

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFM7E.png

Here is my code :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form_contact">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center" >
                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url'); ?>/img/gites/gitedefrance_03.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 " style="background-color: white; margin-left:220px;">
                <h3 class="container"><?php the_field('landing_page_titre_formulaire'); ?></h3>

                <p class="text-center"><?php the_field('landing_page_sous_titre_formulaire'); ?></p>
                <?php the_field('landing_page_formulaire'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using Wordpress to get information of my form

I am trying here to fix my form like in the first picture for every size of my window

Fiddle : http://bootply.com/107224#

Comment: And here is a link to a website where you can code a fiddle to share with us. In order to better help you, believe me, fiddles are better than screenshots. http://bootply.com/new#

Comment: http://bootply.com/107222# Maybe it'll work tell me if you cant see the <img> i will upload them

Comment: "Page Web inaccessible" when following your img src...

Comment: http://bootply.com/107224#